# the server you are trying to connect doesn't have any model

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm new in power bi,I'm using ssas tabular model and have deployed.  but when in Power bi, I wanna use live connect it gives me 'the server you are trying to connect doesn't have any model'. while if I use import, it can find the model. what is the problem with live connect? what is required?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the account you are trying to use has access to the database. If not add permissions to at least read. If it has this proceed to step 2 below.
2. Make sure your database is processed on the SSAS server. The error can happen when the default database is empty on SSAS Tabular or if the default database is unprocessed in SSAS Multidimensional.
3. Uninstall and install the latest version of PowerBI Desktop. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494